# R - Emoji unicode to character

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, emoji, emoticons

I'm coding in R. Let's say that I have the unicode value of an emoji as

```
wink_emoji <- "\U0001f609"
```

Or, alternatively, as

```
wink_emoji <- "U+1f609"
```

Is there a function that I can use to print the actual emoji character to the console? Like this:

```
[1] ""
```

How about as its HTML character entity?

```
[1] "&#128521;"
```

Furthermore, if I have a string like so:

```
test <- "This is a test U+1f609 U+1F469 U+200D U+2764 U+FE0F U+200D U+1F48B U+200D U+1F469"
```

Can I run it through a function to match all of the emojis and return this:

```
[1] "This is a test ‍❤️‍‍"
```

Comment: maybe check out the remoji package?

Comment: `cat("\U0001f609")` (provided your font has the glyphs)

Comment: What about printing emojis requiring multiple unicode values (e.g.: "\U0001F469 \U000200D \U0002764 \U000FE0F \U000200D \U0001F48B \U000200D \U0001F469" renders ‍❤️‍‍)

Comment: Just take out the spaces: `cat(gsub(' ', '', "\U0001F469 \U000200D \U0002764 \U000FE0F \U000200D \U0001F48B \U000200D \U0001F469"))`

Answer (score 3):

Use `utf8_print` from the `utf8` package to print, `utf8ToInt` to get the integer value of the code point:

```
wink_emoji <- "\U0001f609"
utf8::utf8_print(wink_emoji)
#> [1] "​"
utf8ToInt(wink_emoji)
#> [1] 128521
```

(Printing emoji only works on MacOS and Linux, not on Windows.)

Comment: Awesome! This is basically what I was looking for. One more thing, though, what about printing emojis requiring multiple unicode values? (e.g.: how "\U0001F469 \U000200D \U0002764 \U000FE0F \U000200D \U0001F48B \U000200D \U0001F469" should render the ‍❤️‍‍  emoji)

Comment: Support for emoji zwj sequences isn't great. Please file a bug if something isn't working correctly: https://github.com/patperry/r-utf8/issues

Comment: I just fixed your example in the dev version of utf8: https://github.com/patperry/r-utf8/commit/f5e6601b7741a63bfc2dfb0c6cdbbe9ef8f3537c